# Moment adding an hour after formatting

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a date im getting from a mysql database, The date is formatted as follows...

```
2020-06-27T08:00:00.000Z
```

I am then using moment to format it using this format

```
moment( date ).format( 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm' )
```

This then outputs the following...

```
2020-06-27 09:00
```

The date is correct but its adding 1 hour. Is this a timezone issue maybe? Thankyou

Comment: More than likely. What timezone is your browser in?

Comment: im in the uk so i assume uk time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`utcOffset(0)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/)

```js
const formatted = moment('2020-06-27T08:00:00.000Z').utcOffset(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
console.log(formatted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZsWP0vT+akWmvEMkNYgZrPHKU9Ke8nYBPC3dqONp1mY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```